# Facebook unity SDK errors

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I have downloaded FacebookSDK-130924 unity package and when i import the package i got following errors:

> Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs(218,37): error CS0117:
>   `UnityEngine.Security' does not contain a definition for`
>   LoadAndVerifyAssembly'
>
> Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs(226,42): error CS1501: No overload for
>   method `GetType' takes`1' arguments
>
> Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs(237,46): error CS1502: The best
>   overloaded method match for
>   `System.Reflection.MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(params System.Type[])'
>   has some invalid arguments
>
> Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs(237,46): error CS1503: Argument `#1'
>   cannot convert`object' expression to type `System.Type[]'
>
> Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs(247,13): error CS1594: Delegate
>   `FB.RemoteFacebookLoader.LoadedDllCallback' has some invalid arguments
>
> Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs(247,13): error CS1503: Argument `#1'
>   cannot convert`object' expression to type `Facebook.IFacebook'

I am using unity 4.1 free license.

Please help me..

Answer (score 2):

Facebook Unity SDK supports Unity Editor 4.2+.

Try upgrading your Unity Editor.